# Removing specific phrases from textual data (R)

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, r, data-cleaning, unsupervised-learning

I have the following reddit posts and I would like to clean the posts and remove from the data the specific phrase "Click to expand", while keeping all other words within a post the same.

```
#Loading packages
library(tidyverse)
require(readxl)
library(quanteda)
```

#data example

```
dput(df[1:20,c(1,2,3)])
```

output:

```
structure(list(id = 1:20, username = c("106gunner", "CPTMiller", 
"matey1982", "Why so serious", "Joe Maya", "Toomin", "wadtheEel", 
"Witch King", "106gunner", "roronoa_zoro", "yonglimm", "laopokcar_g", 
"nymous", "DragonBlack", "betking", "archon75", "ahkrong", "ahkrong", 
"archon75", "[人言可畏]"), post = c("Was reported in SCMP news source underneath link", 
"Government already said ft or CECA create new good jobs for Singaporean", 
"gunner said Was reported in SCMP news source underneath Singaporean to expand arent u stating the obvious", 
"lightboxclose Close lightboxnext Next lightboxprevious Previous lightboxerror The requested content cannot be loaded Please try again later lightboxstartslideshow Start slideshow lightboxstopslideshow Stop slideshow lightboxfullscreen Full screen lightboxthumbnails Thumbnails lightboxdownload Download lightboxshare Share lightboxzoom Zoom lightboxnewwindow New window lightboxtogglesidebar Toggle sidebar", 
"From personal experience i lost my job to jhk", "ceca ftw", 
"edmw say yes but govt say no Who to believe", "I will welcome ceca if pap have ceca candidates in the Parliament", 
"matey said arent u stating the obvious Click to expand Surprised SCMP news also reported", 
"wadtheEel said edmw say yes but govt say no Who to believe Click to expand I believe the govt Every year we can only produce ish IT uni graduates Got lots of IT jobs opening not enough if only hire them Posted from PCWX using SMGN", 
"SONG BOH", "Lies la Say ICT is a small Ask them how many ceca ICT have become PR or citizen This qn xia suay chan dont dare to answer", 
"Ceca is threatof cos as usual sinkapore like to learn in hard way", 
"CECA pls fug off We must stop these CECA cocaine from further entering into SG to worsen the addiction of CECA PMETs by companies like drug addicts We already had enough of FT office politics from Pinoy JHK and AT and now the CECA ones are really at another level Mo Tak Teng not only in the office but most glaring fact is their behaviour in our common public places are so obnoxious til unbearable Its so sickening to keep seeing CECAs everywhere bring in their spouses and families misbehaving themselves bulldoze their prams and trolleys into lifts without basic cowsense courtesy taking loudly in the lifts with kids try to show off their Inglish practiceasking their parents nonsensical why this why that in irritating accent weird inconsiderate behavior on the streets at work places malls hotels hogging at the counters due to some weird problems they face during payments in the parks even at Botanic Gardens PCB etc totally overwhelming like cannot escape from them anywhere in Spore NBCB Seems that unlike decades ago the BanglasIndian bluecollar FWs roaming and littering everywhere problem has become less of an issue these days they are more Ji Tong so to speak perhaps due to public complaints and more of them being confined to larger dormitories with fullfacilities like cinemas etc Since PAP love them so much maybe we should also build some CECA city maybe at Jurong Island or Pulau Hantu or JB even better nbcb LOL and confined these idiots inside like a lockdown to knock themselves out to prevent them from continuing to unleash their poison to our society Its mindboggling that after so many years PAP is still seemingly either unaware or chose to ignore the toxic culture that CECA is bringing to Singapore and still want to sing praises for them in parliament and the media Best part is they blame and even threaten Singaporeans from bringing up these topics which is already like shit stuck on our faces Such a sad story state we are having now I really hope in next few GEs more talents will join the opposition to quickly take up more seats and eventually kick out these elitist scums from further harming our citizens and the socioeconomic fabric of our society Talk so much also useless Rooks rike this is inevitableGE The New Dawn GE Rise of the Phoenix GE The New Era Unless the kumgong love to remain in this horror state then they reap what they sow", 
"SCMP dun waste our tiam lah TS", "Talk also no used SG local population is split old folks who happy of $ + public service sure vote for Then Jiuhu + Ceca + Ah Thiong that form bulk of new citizen sure vote for No way can win", 
"DragonKnightMaster said u really no logic companies can be run by foreigners but country can anyway we have ceca turned singaporean in our parliament already if u not aware Click to expand You are slapping yourself LOLOLOLOLOLOL Sent from mai dua karchng using GAGT", 
"archon said Talk also no used Singaporean local population is split old folks who happy of $ + public service sure vote for Then Jiuhu + Ceca + Ah Thiong that form bulk of new citizen sure vote for No way can win Click to expand sgdivided Well done LOLOLOLOLOLOL Sent from mai dua karchng using GAGT", 
"Will we have Ah Thiong turned new citizen in parliament", "of cos made things easier for them got free job for them why woud they wanna give it to sinkie 肥水不流外人田吗 dont believe ft create job for sinkie its used by LKY to hookwink daft sinkie which any world leader will laugh to scorn"
)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so using [gsub](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/sub-and-gsub-function-r). Assuming your output shown above is stored in a variable `data`:

```
gsub("Click to expand", "", data$post)
```

Comment: I think it would just be `df$post <- gsub("Click to expand", "", df$post)` or something to that effect.